# Why do I need to append a NUL character to an array?

Tags: c, arrays, character

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char x[] = "Happy birthday to You";
    char y[25]; 
    char z[15];

    printf("The string in array x is: %s\nThe string in array y is: %s\n", x, strcpy(y, x));

    strncpy(z, x, 14);

    z[14] = '\0'; // Why do I need to do this?
    printf("The string in array z is: %s\n", z);
    return 0; 
}
```

1. Why do I need to append a NUL character to the array `z`?
2. Also I commented that line and the output didn't change, Why?
3. And if I do something like `z[20] = '\0';` it's compiling and showing me result without any errors. Isn't that illegal access to memory as I declared my `z` array to be the size of 15?

Comment: Because Mr Kernighan ana Mr Ritchie  had this idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C language does not have native string type. In C, strings are actually one-dimensional array of characters terminated by a null character `\0`.

> *Why do I need to append a `NUL` character to the array `z`?*

C library function, like `strcpy()/strncpy()` operate on null-terminated character array. `strncpy()` copies at most *count* characters from the source to the destination. If it finds the terminating null character, copies it to destination and return. If *count* is reached before the entire source array was copied, the resulting character array is not null-terminated and you need to explicitly add the null terminating character at the end of destination.

> *Also I commented that line and the output didn't change, Why?*

The only thing I can say is you are lucky. Perhaps the last character of destination (i.e. `z[14]`) could have all bits `0`. But this may not happen every time you run your program. Make sure to add the null terminating character explicitly when using `strncpy()` or use some other C library function which do it automatically for you like `snprintf()`.

> *And if I do something like `z[20] = '\0'`; it's compiling and showing me result without any errors. Isn't that illegal access to memory as I declared my `z` array to be the size of 15?*

The size of array `z` is `15` and you are accessing `z[20]` i.e. accessing array `z` beyond its size. In C, accessing array out of bounds is undefined behavior. An undefined behavior includes program may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I need to append a NUL character to the array z?

From the `strncpy` man:

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if
>   source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not
>   be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would
>   overflow).

---

> Also I commented that line and the output didn't change, Why?

My guess is: `z` was already initialized to `0` (you can not rely on this for arrays with non static storage duration)

---

> Isn't that illegal access to memory as I declared my z array to be the
>   size of 15?

Yes, out-of-bounds array accesses have undefined behavior, and can result in crashes or incorrect program output.

If you want to avoid hardcoding the NUL terminator, you can switch to `snprintf`:

```
snprintf(z, sizeof z, "%.*s", 14, x);
```

Answer (score 1):

In C all `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. All string functions use the null-terminator to know where the strings end, as they can't otherwise know the length of a string (don't forget that arrays decays to *pointers* to their first element, and pointer have no information about what they point to except the type).

Also note that there are cases when [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) will *not* automatically terminate the destination, which means you have to do it explicitly. Your use in the example is one such case.

If a string is not terminated the string functions can go out of bounds searching for it, and that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Unfortunately one of the possibilities of UB is to *seemingly* work.

Lastly, uninitialized local non-static (a.k.a. "automatic") variables, including arrays, will have *indeterminate* (and seemingly random) values and contents. You could be "lucky" that `z[14]` just happens to contain a zero.

Comment: yeah but i want to understand why it won't affect the performance i.e. the output etc.

Comment: @Stanley Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. > Why do I need to append a NUL character to the array `z`?

   `%s` in `printf` prints everything until a NUL-terminator. If you don't add the NUL-terminator at the end, `printf` will go on accessing invalid memory locations beyond the array until a NUL-terminator invoking Undefined Behavior.
2. > Also I commented that line and the output didn't change, Why?

   Consider yourself *unlucky* that the `z[14]` had a NUL-terminator. This isn't guaranteed and you still invoke Undefined Behavior.
3. > And if I do something like `z[20] = '\0';` it's compiling and showing me result without any errors. Isn't that illegal access to memory as I declared my `z` array to be the size of 15?

   C is a loosely typed language and does not do any bound checking. All power rests in the hands of the programmer and you should be coding stuff properly.

   Yes, it accesses illegal memory. This invokes Undefined Behavior which means that anything could happen. Consider yourself *unlucky* that it didn't crash or anything

Comment: "*C is a loosely typed language*" well, no. Right the opposite, it's very strictly typed.

Comment: @alk, so you mean, I should get a _stronger_ keyboard? ;-)